# Keep getting 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object'

Tags: hibernate, jboss, dependencies

I keep getting

```
'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object'
```

when trying to instantiate Hibernate [`StandardServiceRegistryBuilder`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/registry/StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.html). I read through several other articles related to this issue, but none of those helped.

Most answers refer to using multiple JBoss JARs, but my project is only using the ones required by Hibernate 4.3 ->
[My Project's .jar references].

[image]

I don't see any conflicting JAR references, and I tried removing all JBoss JARs individually, but it throws the same exact error every time. I am not using any other JBoss-related code in my project. Also, I am not using Maven for this project, so please do not provide answers related to Maven (most of the answers I've found are Maven specific).

Thank you!

Comment: I also tried adding in the JBoss Common Core .jar to see if that would help. Still got the exact same error.

Comment: I also created a new HibernateTest project in Eclipse and setup Hibernate exactly how I am using it in this project. The test project works fine, so it must be something very specific to this project. I was wondering if the Log4J was the issue, so I implemented Log4J in the test project and it did not affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by replacing the `${JBOSS_HOME}\modules\org\jboss\logging\main\jboss-logging-<version>.jar` for the newest one. You can download it [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final). Also, do not forget to update the related `module.xml`.